# data lake file to blob poor performance

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azcopy

I'm using azcopy to upload local files to a blob storage.

I'm using command:

```
azcopy copy "localpath" "destinationpath(with SAS)" --include="*.csv" --recursive=true
```

I also tried

```
azcopy sync "localpath" "destinationpath(with SAS)" --include="*.csv"
```

The files I'm trying to upload are each 1GB+.
When I manually upload a file to the data lake it takes 40min+ for 1 file. If I do it with azcopy it takes 30min+ per file and often fails.

Is it normal that it takes this long? Am I doing something wrong or is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: you're uploading to blob storage or azure data lake(gen 1 or gen 2)?

Comment: @IvanYang gen1 blob storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, the azcopy is optimized for better performance. I see your code, nothing is missing. If that's the case, we can do nothing(or maybe you can check if it's network issue?).

You can take a try with [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-data-lake-store#load-data-into-data-lake-storage-gen1), it provides very high performance which can be up to 1-GB/s data loading speed into Data Lake Storage Gen1.

Comment: Yes, we just found the problem. We have to use a proxy, but apparently the proxy is being throttled and gave us very bad upload speed. We talked to our network team and now it is solved, so it was indeed a network related problem.